# How do I simulate a short/open circuit in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, opto-isolator, short-circuit, optoelectronics

I am trying to simulate open/short conditions for testing an optoisolator circuit I'm building.

Essentially, I need to simulate SHORT and OPEN in order to verify that what I'm designing will output the desired voltage difference instead of either infinite or none.

Here is an image of the part I'm playing with. It uses a PC817 as the photocoupler, and I'm building a box with two of them where one functions just as an isolator, and the other functions to translate a sensor from purely outputting OPEN or SHORT conditions, to different voltages so our devices can read it. In short, I need to know how to simulate OPEN and SHORT conditions to verify that the circuit I make will do what I need it to.

[image: Image of the part I'm playing with1]

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what you want to achieve. It'd help if you could post a schematic and mark what you want to "open" and "short".

Comment: Maybe a voltage controlled switch (symbol name _SW_).

Comment: Define your question better with part number , output specs, ambient, supply and interface specs

Comment: I think the simplest method which still includes the interaction between LED and photo-transistor, would be a zero-volt voltage source in series with a diode and then using that voltage source to control either a high gain [F-source](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=F_Current_Dependent_Current_Source) or a [W-switch](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=W_Current_Controlled_Switch).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways, one is using a relay or switch to change a load (A resistor with 1e9Ω is a good approximation for an Open condtion and something small like 1mΩ is good for simulating a short).

Another way to do this is to use a [variable resistor](https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/resources/simulating-time-variable-resistors.59/#:%7E:text=LTSPICE%20allows%20control%20of%20the%20resistance%20of%20a,output%20net%20with%20a%20descriptive%20name%20%28e.g.%20Vresistance%29.) (a regular resistor with the value set to R=V(node).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet as I elected to try it out with physical parts, but I'll definitely try these things out as I'm trying to get used to LTSpice anyways and need to know how to simulate things like this.

Comment: In case you run into convergence problems use a VCSW (`F2` > `sw`) with *negative* hysteresis in the `.model` card (see the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > S. ...* for more). A `level=1` will do.

Answer (score 0):

The CTR is rated for a stated input current and output current and Vce.

CTR is the product of optical coupling , k and hFE of the transistor.

As in all transistors, the hFE drops to about 10% of max linear hFE when tested for saturation.

- If you understand saturation begins when C-B junction diode becomes forward biased with respect to the base of the B-E junction or typ. Vbe= Vce = 0.6V @ Ic= 1mA(depending on Ic)
- a loaded current gain will drop if the output is shorted to a supply at 0.1V vs 0.6V vs a pullup current limiter to 5V with Vce = 1V

When Vce >> 0.6V like Vce=2V, then it is operating as a current sink with high impedance. When operating at Vce<1V it starts to operate as a voltage switch with low impedance but lower current gain.

- You determine the worst case Vol max for a logic level or analog level. The Input current at worst case temp and comp. tolerances to guarantee Vol. from CTR min rated at your Vol max.